# Make "System" process not modifiable from Task Manager like it is the case in Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, command-line, perfmon

FYI : I have **Windows-7 Ultimate Ver 6.1 Service-Pack 1**.

There is a tools in the Windows-7 that called *Resource Monitor* . You can find it in `C:\Windows\System32` directory or you also can simply run it via *resmon.exe* in the *Run*.

In the list of processes there is a process named **`System`** and its **PID** is equal to **`4`** always.

[image]

If you right-click on it and click on *`Suspend Process`* , your computer will hang, your mouse and keyboard will disable, and you have to turn *restart* your system to getting back to normal state.

[image]

In the ***Windows-8*** even if you logged with a Administrator account, you can't suspend this process (*System*) and when you try to suspend it, you receive *`Access Denied`*

**Q1: Why Microsoft corporation provide this capability for Administrator to suspend System Process? When we need to suspend it and make or system hang?!**

**Q2: Is there any way in Windows-7 to config the system so that even Administrator can not suspend this process?**

---

**If you think there is no way to do that, please read the below :**

We can have a list of `*.dll` files that are related to a process with below command in *Command-Prompt* :

**`>tasklist /FI "PID eq Number" /M`**

And you can have a list of PID numbers in the *resmon.exe* tool.(You can also use `tasklist` command in *Command-Line* windows).

In my system PID of *resmon.exe* is `1728` (Its process name is *perfmon*).

Let see a list of `.dll` files related to *resmon.exe* :

```
C:\Windows\system32>tasklist /FI "PID eq 1728" /M

Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
perfmon.exe                   1728 ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KERNELBASE.dll,
                                   ADVAPI32.dll, msvcrt.dll, sechost.dll,
                                   RPCRT4.dll, GDI32.dll, USER32.dll, LPK.dll,
                                   USP10.dll, ATL.DLL, ole32.dll, SHLWAPI.dll,
                                   SHELL32.dll, OLEAUT32.dll, credui.dll,
                                   Secur32.dll, SSPICLI.DLL, IMM32.DLL,
                                   MSCTF.dll, comctl32.dll, uxtheme.dll,
                                   dwmapi.dll, CRYPTBASE.dll, CLBCatQ.DLL,
                                   wdc.dll, DUser.dll, pdh.dll, pdhui.dll,
                                   COMDLG32.dll, ODBC32.dll, wevtapi.dll,
                                   VERSION.dll, PLA.dll, tdh.dll, NSI.dll,
                                   IPHLPAPI.DLL, WINNSI.DLL, WINSTA.dll,
                                   UTILDLL.dll, SETUPAPI.dll, CFGMGR32.dll,
                                   DEVOBJ.dll, NETAPI32.dll, netutils.dll,
                                   srvcli.dll, wkscli.dll, LOGONCLI.DLL,
                                   BROWCLI.DLL, SAMCLI.DLL, WTSAPI32.dll,
                                   VDMDBG.dll, odbcint.dll, DUI70.dll,
                                   xmllite.dll, OLEACC.dll, FirewallAPI.dll,
                                   profapi.dll, WS2_32.dll, msxml3.dll,
                                   ntmarta.dll, WLDAP32.dll, Perfctrs.dll,
                                   perfdisk.dll, mswsock.dll, DNSAPI.dll,
                                   dhcpcsvc6.DLL, dhcpcsvc.DLL, WINTRUST.dll,
                                   CRYPT32.dll, MSASN1.dll, pcwum.dll,
                                   rasadhlp.dll

C:\Windows\system32>
```

**Note : You have to run Command-Prompt as Administrator**

**Q3: If I copy the above `.dll` files from Windows-8 directory and replace Windows-7 `.dll` files with them, does windows-7 will behave like Windows-8? (Prevent suspending System process)**

**Note: Assume that we use a live windows CD and a flash memory to Replace dll files. (Normally Windows-7 don't let you to replace `.dll` files)**

Really appreciate your time and consideration :)

Comment: The `System` process is basically the operating system itself. As to why you can suspend it, only Microsoft can answer. Usually Windows *tries* to prevent users from doing harmful things, but it doesn't always succeed: users will eventually find new ways to break the system, be it intentionally or by mistake. Some people dislike a babysitting system, others don't; you can't really please both. No matter what method you use, copying Windows 8 system files over Windows 7 ones is a probably good idea if you want to make it unusable. Also, please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: @and31415 Thank you dear friend. but this questions are deeply related and related to the title, I guess :)

Comment: explain why you want to do this (nonsense). Which issues do you have?

Comment: NO, probably if you copy it Windows 7 won't behave as Windows 8. But there is only one way to find out for sure ....  ;)

Comment: Now that sounds like a surefire plan to break a Windows installation

Comment: The System process is NOT "basically the operating system itself". It is a wrapper for kernel mode threads used not just by the OS but also by many components in networking, file systems, ... many others. The reason that suspending it kills mouse and keyboard input is that the threads that read these devices are in this process. But many things in Windows can continue running even while this process is suspended.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I want to change Windows 7 security policy and settings in a way that Administrator can not suspend `System` process! I think the questions are really clear!

Comment: no one can suspend the Kernel without killing Windows. Without the kernel nothing works.

Comment: @magicandre1981 would you please read the question carefully!? You misunderstand the question! As I said, I can suspend the `System` process and make my computer crash! I want to restrict this capability! Why admin must have this ability?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: No good reason I can think of; it seems to be an oversight.

Q2: No, because I can do it in my Win8.1 system too. I just did. The Administrators group already does not have the "Suspend/resume process" access right to this process, so how this is working at all, I'm not sure.

Q3: See above. I get the same behavior on Win8.1 so obviously using files from Win8.1 won't help. Also, those DLLs are not likely to be at all happy in the Win8 environment, and are shared by many other programs. You'll break a whole bunch of stuff if you try that.

Sorry..

Comment: If _Remote Desktop_ was enabled in my system, then I suspend the **System** process LOCALLY, is there any way to resume **System** by remote desktop? thanks

Comment: FYI I have ping of the system when System suspended.

Comment: Ping - yes. Suspending the System process doesn't suspend everything in the OS, only those functions implemented in the System process's threads. Re rd, you would have to have a program ready to run that would call NtResumeProcess and could be triggered without needing anything from the System process. I don't know of anything offhand.

Comment: I am very curious as to why, on my Windows 8.1 test system here, I can suspend the System process from TM (and from Process Explorer), but you cannot. Can you verify that this is the case for you?

Comment: Oops! That's weird! Yes, I'm sure, In my Windows-7 Ultimate ver6.1 I can suspend `System` process, But my friend in Windows-8 can't suspend it (with Administrator user)- (I'm not sure about the version of his Windows-8 , but I think it is not important, the question is why?! and how we can change it?) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and change permissions with [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
2. On the process properties view, select the security tab.
3. Press the permissions button.
4. Press the advanced button.
5. If necessary, add yourself or a group you belong to.
6. Edit your permisisons to include "Terminate". (you will need to
   already have the "Change Permissions" permisison, or you are out of
   luck.)

OR

It is because the permissions of System (ntoskrnl.exe), are set to "read and write", and are only editable by "Trusted Installer" to prevent noobs from doing damage to their own computer. This includes ending the process itself. You need "Full Control". To fix this simply go to "C:\Windows\System32", right click on "ntoskrnl.exe", and the properties, then click the "security" tab, then go to "Advanced", and then click on "Full Control" for administrator. Now you would be able to end it from Resource Monitor

Comment: Sorry but... he doesn't WANT to "end it", he wants to NOT be able to suspend it. And besides, changing the permissions on ntoskrnl.exe will do nothing. The System process is not created to run an instance of ntoskrnl.exe (and there is no exe called "System"), nor does the ACL of an exe get propagated to its process anyway. The important access right here is "suspend/create process" and it cannot even be set for files.

Comment: Ok then, why when I go into task manager and right click on "System" and click "Open File Location" it takes me to ntoskrnl.exe in system32?

Comment: Also, why when I run all the ntoskrnl.exe (with the DLL's injected of course), in VMWare it restores the System process when it is suspended.

Comment: @kirill2485 Thank you, but as Mr Jamie said, I want to not be able to suspend it .And when I use `> tasklist /FI "PID eq 4" /M`  in **Command-Line**, It return no module for it!  more when I right click on `System` and click on _Open file location_ it opens Desktop!

Comment: Maybe you are not doing something I'm doing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cuDjumkkmQdmtteV93OHljY3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, Process Explorer works vise-versa, you can prevent the access

Comment: kirill: You might ask yourself why, if the System process is launched as an instance of ntoskrnl.exe, that is not displayed as the "image" name? It's a very special case. ("Idle" is another, there is no idle.exe, the idle thread routine is part of ntoskrnl.)  It is true that a great many of the threads in the process are running routines in ntoskrnl... but many come from other modules. ntoskrnl is not "run" like any other image, it is simply mapped into the kernel address space of ALL processes. This is all well documented in _Windows Internals_.

Comment: TheGoodUser: Tasklist is giving you a more "real" look at things than Task Manager does. The actual ImageFileName field in "System"'s EPROCESS structure contains "System", but there is no system.exe, so it shows nothing. That TM takes you to ntoskrnl.exe is due to special-case code in TM.